# Type not being instantiated correctly by StructureMap (using XML configuration)

Tags: structuremap, xml-configuration

OK, I'm stumped over a seemingly trivial piece of functionality.

How can I get StructureMap to initialize the properties on type instances retrieved from the container, using XML configuration (unfortunately I have to use XML)?

My current code is:

**The type and interface:**

```
public interface IMyType
{
  decimal MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public MyType : IMyType
{
  public decimal MyProperty {get; set; }
}
```

**The container initialization and instance retrieval code:**

```
ObjectFactory
  .Initialize(x => x.AddConfigurationFromXmlFile(@"StructureMap.config"));
IMyType instance = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IMyType>("Blah"); 
var myPropertyValue = instance.MyProperty; //expected 1, is actually 0
```

**XML Configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StructureMap MementoStyle="Attribute">  
  <AddInstance
    PluginType="MyNamespace.IMyType, MyAssemblyName"
    PluggedType="MyNamespace.MyType, MyAssemblyName"
    Key="Blah"
    Name="Blah
    MyProperty="1" />
</StructureMap>
```

Comment: Having tested the above, it works; likely a container initialization problem. Am investigating.

Comment: Suspect a typing issue - a string property works, decimal does not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a typing issue with StructureMap. Using an int, float or double works. Using a decimal does not.

Workaround is to use another floating point type such as float or double.